# Select rows with same id but different values in another column grouped by a third column

Tags: sql, select, data-analysis

I have a table like this:

| ID | CODE | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 123 |
| 1 | A | 456 |
| 1 | C | 123 |
| 1 | B | 789 |
| 2 | A | 344 |
| 2 | B | 344 |

I would like to see all cases that for the same ID we have different values for different codes.

Result:
ID 1, CODE B VALUE 789 NOT FOUND
ID 1, CODE A VALUE 456 NOT FOUND

In summary I need to see all diferences the I didn't find on column VALUE based in the ID key BUT NOT FOR THE SAME "CODE" COLUMN.

Anyone know how to achive that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Provided no duplicate rows exist, i.e. (ID, CODE, VALUE) is unique you can find VALUEs  associated with exactly one CODE each with

```
select ID, max(CODE) CODE, VALUE
from tbl
group by ID, VALUE
having count(*) = 1
```